# Example of matrices with some interesting properties like same characteristic and minimal polynomial etc.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Looking for  two matrices $A$ and $B$ with entries in the field  $F_2$   with the following properties:

$A$ and $B$ both are invertible,have same minimal polynomial,Characteristic polynomial,same dimension of each eigenspace and both are not conjugate to each other.

I can think of matrices which have some properties like have same characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial but I am unable in finding example with all above proprties.Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the questions asks about similar matrices, the first idea is to think about matrices $A$ and $B$ in Jordan form with exactly one eigenvalue. Then the characteristic polynomials will agree. Since dimension of eigenspace is equal the number of Jordan blocks, $A$ and $B$ should have same number of Jordan blocks. Since $A$ and $B$ should have same minimal polynomial, the largest Jordan blocks of $A$ and $B$ have to be equal.

It turns out [see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385064/nilpotent-matrices-with-same-minimal-polynomial-and-nullity?rq=1) that the minimal size, where this is possible, is $7$.

Take
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1&1&1&&&&\\
&1&1&&&&\\
&&1&&&&\\
&&&1&1&1&\\
&&&&1&1&\\
&&&&&1&\\
&&&&&&1
},
\quad
B = \pmatrix{
1&1&1&&&&\\
&1&1&&&&\\
&&1&&&&\\
&&&1&1&&\\
&&&&1&&\\
&&&&&1&1\\
&&&&&&1
}
$$
Their minimal polyniomial is $(t-1)^3$, the characteristic polynomial is $(t-1)^7$, the dimension of the eigenspace to eigenvalue $1$ is $3$.
They are not similar (or conjugate), as 
$$
5 = \dim\ker((I-A)^2)\ne\dim\ker((I-B)^2)=6.
$$

Comment: Can  u please give me idea to construct such example?

Comment: see edited answer