# $5 \times 5$ nilpotent matrices with the same minimal polynomial and nullity must be similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

**Problem.** 
 Suppose $A, B$ are both $5 \times 5$ nilpotent complex matrices with the same nullity and the same minimal polynomial. Prove that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

**My Question.** 
 Is there a 'clever' way to do this?

I did it by cases: If nullity = 1, 4, or 5, then only 1 JCF is possible. If nullity = 2, then there are two possible JCFs, but they have different minimal polynomials; same if nullity = 3. So in short, if $A$ and $B$ share the same nullity and minimal polynomial, then they share the same JCF. So, does this seem like a correct approach? And also, anytime I'm doing something by cases, I always wonder if there's a more elegant way of handling all the cases at once?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385064/nilpotent-matrices-with-same-minimal-polynomial-and-nullity?rq=1). It is true for $n=5,6$, but no longer true for $n=7$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nilpotent matrices with same minimal polynomial and nullity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385064/nilpotent-matrices-with-same-minimal-polynomial-and-nullity)

Comment: Thank you; I did see that post during my research. My question is more about proof technique than linear algebra theory; more so: is it possible to prove something like this without just going through all the cases (nullify = 1, then … nullify = 2, then … etc); or is the appropriate thing to do in questions like this to go through the cases?

Comment: No, it is not really possible with a general proof without cases, because it becomes false for all $n\ge 7$. And for Jordan blocks of nilpotent $5\times 5$-matrices there are not so many cases. We have $p(5)=7$, the number of partitions of $5$. So to look at a few cases with Jordan blocks is already quite clever.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great answer. I like the perspective that it “becomes false”, I hadn’t thought about it that way.